# Date and Time parameters in Eclipse Birt

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, amazon-redshift, birt

The current report has data parameter already and the client wants to add time that coincide with the date parameter present. My datasets include 2 generate_series, 1 for date range and 1 for time range

Newbie in Birt but has experience in SQL. Tried giving time condition but didnt work

```
select 
cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoff = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoff end,1,3) as int),cast(transacttime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date) date,
to_char(cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoff = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoff end,1,3) as int),cast(transacttime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date),'dd/MM/yyyy') datetext,
to_char(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoff = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoff end,1,3) as int),cast(transacttime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)),'HH24:MI:SS') trans_time
from import_table 
where
cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoff= 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoff end,1,3) as int),cast(transacttime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date) >= ?
and cast(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoff = 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoff end,1,3) as int),cast(transacttime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)) as date) < dateadd(day,1,?)
```

and to_char(dateadd(h,cast(substring(case when timezoneoff= 'Z' then '0' else timezoneoffend,1,3) as int),cast(transacttime::timestamp as timestamp without time zone)),'HH24:MI:SS')between ? and ?;

no output as I am getting an error. Im hoping to get a start date and be able to choose the time and end it with date and a time as well. Example:

start date: 15/01/2019
start time: 2PM
end date: 16/01/2019
end time: 8AM

Comment: my data sets are from generate_series for both time and date

Comment: Try to add your code in formatted in code. or Please go through How to ask.

Comment: I can see two `where` conditions back to back, can you please check if that's a typo?

Comment: that's just a typo

Comment: R V sorry just really new here.will try to read more